# How to make selectable states in Australia (web map)?

Tags: javascript, html, gis

The following link provided is something that I am after for a web mapping project.

http://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/samples/fl_dgrid/

The following link contains the utilisation of ESRI base layer map, and what seems to be a layer polygon possibly created in Arcmap, which allows users to select individual states, which when selected displays in a table.

I am trying to achieve the similar user interaction but just for Australia; for example, users will be able to select Western Australia, Northern territory est, which would then show which state the user selected in a table and generate data/information.

So far from my understanding, it seems as though ArcGIS for server could have been used in order to save the feature polygon layer, which is then called as a service from the coding and generated onto the base layer map of ESRI.

I am wondering if anyone can help me in terms of how to get this user interaction working just for a map of Australia. Would I create the polygon layer in arcmap, make that as a service using ArcGIS for server and then call it from coding?

Also, for the actual selection of each state and showing in a table, my understanding is javascript is used?

I guess I am just trying to get a more thorough understanding so I can go on from there, in order to create something similar just for Australia. Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: If this is just a single image then you could use the HTML image map and use mouseover or click events to show the details of the area selected.

Comment: Hi jeff, thanks for your comment. I have looked into using HTML images, however the problem is the map will need to support zooming in, as there are individual point features within each region, that cant be seen clearly if the map is at full extent.

Comment: see: http://raphaeljs.com/world/ for svg+js version or http://www.evomorf.com/html-css-jquery/pure-htmlcss-clickable-australia-map/

Comment: thanks for the links technosaurus.

Answer (score 0):

There are probably a few different ways to go about getting this to work depending on what data you have available to you. My answer is based off what I see in the example you posted.

Assuming you had the polygons for Australia available to you, you should be able to modify the example and have a working version pretty easily.

**Grid**
For the grid, it looks like they are using the dgrid plugin which unfortunately I have no experience with so you would need to look up info on that.

**Map**
If you are wanting to have a polygon shown for each state/territory then you would need to have a service with all the polygon objects available to you. Not sure if this is already available or if you would need to create each polygon somehow.

When the map loads you would want to load all the polygons. When a user clicks on a state you would want to create a query to select the given polygon so that it is highlighted (they are using the OBJECTID field in the example which would be unique to each polygon). When selecting the polygon in the map you would also select the row in the grid(This is also done by the ID aka OBJECTID field from the polygon).

Comment: thanks itsthejash, very helpful, gave me a bit more understanding on how to proceed. I will definitely look into dgrid, and hopefully I can get something going.